# Why wont this move a file while running?

Tags: python

So, I made this little "application" that checks if a file ends with a specific extension(.png or .jpg), but my issue is if I turn it into a loop and I download something while the loop is running it won't move the file to the intended location. It only moves the file on startup.

```
import os
import shutil

DownloadsDir = ""
Downloadslst = os.listdir(DownloadsDir) 
ImageFolder = ''

while True:
    for files in Downloadslst:
        if files.endswith(('.png','.jpg')):
            shutil.move(DownloadsDir + files, ImageFolder)
            print("File moved succefully.")
```

Comment: Is `Downloadslst = os.listdir(DownloadsDir)` inside the loop? If not, then it should be inside the loop

Comment: yes, do you think that is the issue? 
Edit: now that i think about it no.

Comment: Yes it is. Try it

Comment: I forgot the while loop when I posted this... my bad, do you think you could look again?

Comment: `.jpg` has a dot in front but `png` not...

Comment: @wuerfelfreak No matter tbh, `endswith`.

Comment: Alright, so after correcting everything and adding the os.listdir into my loop it works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir(...)` is a one-time operation that lists all the files in the current directory at the point of calling. The collection is fixed, not dynamically updated; it's just a simple `list`. And `lists` don't update themselves based on a seemingly random condition, like when the files inside a directory change. If you want your list to stay updated, you need to call the function multiple times.

I would do:

```
processed = set()
to_process = set()

while has_smth_to_download:
    download_some_files()
    for item in os.listdir(DownloadsDir):
        if item not in processed:
             to_process.add(item)
             processed.add(item)
    for files in to_process:
        if files.endswith(('png','.jpg')):
            shutil.move(DownloadsDir + files, ImageFolder)
            print("File moved succefully.")
    to_process.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import os
import shutil

DownloadsDir = ""
ImageFolder = ''

while True:
    Downloadslst = os.listdir(DownloadsDir) 
    for files in Downloadslst:
        if files.endswith(('.png','.jpg')):
            shutil.move(DownloadsDir + files, ImageFolder)
            print("File moved succefully.")
```